# Installing kafka-connect-spooldir doesn't work

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

When I try to install `kafka-connect-spooldir` with `confluent-hub` :

```
confluent-hub install jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir:1.0.31
```

The output :

```
Do you want to install this into /usr/share/confluent-hub-components? (yN) y

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: 
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: 
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Error: Unknown error
```

**Edit:**

It didn't work but I have a clue: **downloading the jars of the connector**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are attempting to run `confluent-hub install` behind a proxy. If this is the case, then the following should do the trick:

```
export http_proxy=MY_PROXY_ADDRESS
export https_proxy=MY_PROXY_ADDRESS
confluent-hub install jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir:1.0.31
```

Comment: I don't think that I use a proxy, or maybe you are talking about a native proxy created by kafka.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the certificate needed to be provided by the company I work with

Comment: I am the author